# Is it possible to use/run/call a Modelica FMI model in R?

Tags: r, modelica, fmi

I will get a compiled model (FMU Function mockup unit) from a third-party software company coded in Modelica (Dymola).

Is it possible to run / use this model within R environnement, i.e. import it, simulate it and get results from it ?

The interface is an FMI (functional Mockup Interface)

Answer (score 1):

I have never heard of an FMI import implementation in R (and I am not familier at all with R ...) What I naively would try:

Use one of the existing implementations for FMI import in Python (https://github.com/CATIA-Systems/FMPy, https://github.com/modelon-community/PyFMI, ...) or C (https://github.com/modelon-community/fmi-library), and call these from R via some standard package (reticulate, .C, ...)